# Submit a form using a specific user agent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Here is one I was pondering on today and did not know of a way to accomplish this.

Is there any possible way to have a html form that submits using a specific user agent?

Say for instance you are using a desktop browser and have a form that you would want to submit as a mobile browser, so having the ability to have a drop-down list of different mobile user-agents could be a fun way to accomplish this.

I had never given consideration to this before about 30 minutes ago. Quick search around the internet did not yield any results.

How can we programmatically spoof the user agent? Any method via pure javascript, jquery, or any other web based libraries out there that could make this happen?

Comment: Just wondering, why do you have to send forms using specific user agent and not all? Just curious though.

Comment: There are browser plugins which will let you do this, which is probably the easiest way.  Otherwise you will need to use JS to do a backend AJAX query to submit the form, and you can add headers there.

Comment: To change user agent you just need to change `User-Agent` header in request, but if you try to do this in browser js app, you get something like this `Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"` (jquery exception)

Comment: If you want to simulate mobile devices, you can use Chrome Developer Tools: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/mobile/